# String to Int throwing a NumberFormatException

Tags: kotlin, numberformatexception

I am wanting to convert a String to an Int.

The String, in question, is `1585489022235`.

I have to convert to a String, first, which appears to be successful (I am printing out the above).

```
val id = data.get("id").toString()

println(id)

val toInt = id.toInt()
```

When I attempt to convert from a String to an Int, this exception is thrown:

```
 Error Message: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1585489022235"
        Stacktrace: 
        java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
        java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
        java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `"1585489022235"` can't be converted to an `Int` because it is greater than the maximum value of the data type `Int` which you can get by `Int.MAX_VALUE` and it is equal to `2147483647`.
What you can do is covert the string to `Long`:

```
val x = id.toLong()
```

The maximum value of the data type long is `9223372036854775807`, which you can get by `Long.MAX_VALUE`.
You can find more here: [Basic Types - Numbers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, `Int` and `Long` are both numeric data types, but they represent different ranges of values. The key differences between `Int` and `Long` are in their size and the range of values they can store:

### Size:

`Int`: 32 bits (4 bytes)

`Long`: 64 bits (8 bytes)

### Value Range:

`Int`: Ranges from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1

`Long`: Ranges from -2^63 to 2^63 - 1

The choice between `Int` and `Long` depends on the specific requirements of your application. Here are some considerations:

- **Memory Usage:** `Long` uses twice as much memory as `Int` because it is 64 bits compared to 32 bits. If you have a large collection of integers and memory usage is a concern, using `Int` might be more efficient.
- **Range of Values:** If your application needs to represent values larger than the range of `Int` (e.g., timestamps, unique identifiers, etc.), you should use `Long` to avoid potential overflow issues.
- **Performance:** Operations on `Int` may be faster than on `Long` because they involve smaller data sizes. However, modern processors are optimized for working with both data types, and the performance difference may not be significant in many cases.

In your specific scenario, where you're dealing with numeric values that might exceed the range of `Int`, using `toLong()` is a reasonable approach. It ensures that your application can handle larger values without encountering overflow issues.

Keep in mind that choosing the appropriate data type is also influenced by the semantics of your data. If the values you're working with logically represent integers and fall within the range of `Int`, it makes sense to use `Int`. If your data requires a larger range, then `Long` is the appropriate choice.